# Почему то fastapi_users при авторизации возвращает токен, но не авторизует

Tags: python, fastapi

Регистрация проходит успешно, юзер создается, но вот логин тоже происходит, токен дает, а сам не авторизует, когда пытаюсь сделать logout говорит что я не авторизован
код:

`database.py`:

```
from datetime import datetime
from typing import AsyncGenerator

from fastapi import Depends
from uuid import UUID
import uuid
from typing import List
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Boolean, TIMESTAMP, ForeignKey, Integer, JSON
from fastapi_users.db import SQLAlchemyBaseUserTableUUID, SQLAlchemyUserDatabase, SQLAlchemyBaseOAuthAccountTable, SQLAlchemyBaseUserTable
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession, async_sessionmaker, create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, Mapped

DATABASE_URL = f"postgresql+asyncpg://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASS}@{DB_HOST}:{DB_PORT}/{DB_NAME}"


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class Role(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'role'
    id: Mapped[int] = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, unique=True)
    name: Mapped[String] = Column(String, nullable=False)
    permissions: Mapped[JSON] = Column(JSON)

    user: Mapped['User']  = relationship(back_populates='role')


class User(SQLAlchemyBaseUserTable[int], Base):
    id: Mapped[int] = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    email: Mapped[str] = Column(String, nullable=False)
    hashed_password: Mapped[str] = Column(String, nullable=False)
    is_active: Mapped[bool] = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=True)
    is_superuser: Mapped[bool] = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    is_verified: Mapped[bool] = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    
    role: Mapped[List['Role']] = relationship(back_populates='user')
    role_id: Mapped[int] = Column(ForeignKey('role.id'))


engine = create_async_engine(DATABASE_URL)
async_session_maker = async_sessionmaker(engine, expire_on_commit=False)

async def create_db_and_tables():
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)

async def get_async_session() -> AsyncGenerator[AsyncSession, None]:
    async with async_session_maker() as session:
        yield session


async def get_user_db(session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_async_session)):
    yield SQLAlchemyUserDatabase(session, User)
```

`schemas.py`:

```
from typing import Optional
import uuid
from fastapi_users import schemas


class UserCreate(schemas.BaseUserCreate):
    role_id: int


class UserRead(schemas.BaseUser[int]):
    pass
```

`main.py`:

```
from datetime import datetime
from enum import Enum
from typing import List, Optional
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi import Depends
from auth.auth import auth_backend
from fastapi_users import FastAPIUsers
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from auth.manager import get_user_manager
from auth.database import User
from auth.schemas import UserRead, UserCreate
from uuid import UUID
from auth.database import create_db_and_tables


app = FastAPI(
    title='Trading app'
)

fastapi_users = FastAPIUsers[User, UUID](
    get_user_manager,
    [auth_backend],
)

app.include_router(
    fastapi_users.get_auth_router(auth_backend),
    prefix="/auth/jwt",
    tags=['auth']
)

app.include_router(
    fastapi_users.get_register_router(UserRead, UserCreate),
    prefix="/auth",
    tags=["auth"],
)

current_user = fastapi_users.current_user()

@app.get("/protected_route")
def protected(user: User = Depends(current_user)):
    return f"Hello {user.email}"
```

`auth.py`:

```
from fastapi_users.authentication import CookieTransport, JWTStrategy, AuthenticationBackend

cookie_transport = CookieTransport(cookie_max_age=3600, cookie_name='trades')


SECRET = "SECRET"

def get_jwt_strategy() -> JWTStrategy:
    return JWTStrategy(secret=SECRET, lifetime_seconds=3600)


auth_backend = AuthenticationBackend(
    name='jwt',
    transport=cookie_transport,
    get_strategy=get_jwt_strategy,
)
```